# Is it possible to hook CommandBarComboBox.Change event such that when a change has been made from Excel VBA code it fires event?

Tags: excel, vba, events, combobox

I have a ComboBox control on a custom CommandBar. I want to detect when a change has been made to the ComboBox and run some code.

This works fine when the user changes the value in the ComboxBox, but if some other VBA code changes it, the Event is not fired.

I have taken the code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcombobox.change
and modified it slightly to delete a CommandBar with the same name so I can run it a number of times. I have then added another function to change the value of the ComboBox programmatically. When I change the value programmatically it can be seen to change on the Excel GUI, but the event code does not fire.

I have also tried the easier OnAction method, rather than hooking events, both seem to give the same result.

In a ClassModule called ComboBoxHandler I have the following code:

```
Private WithEvents ComboBoxEvent As Office.CommandBarComboBox
Public Sub SyncBox(box As Office.CommandBarComboBox)
    Set ComboBoxEvent = box
    If Not box Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Synced " & box.Caption & " ComboBox events."
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set ComboBoxEvent = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxEvent_Change(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarComboBox)
    Dim stComboText As String

    stComboText = Ctrl.Text

        Select Case stComboText
        Case "First Class"
            FirstClass
        Case "Business Class"
            BusinessClass
        Case "Coach Class"
            CoachClass
        Case "Standby"
            Standby
    End Select

End Sub
Private Sub FirstClass()
    MsgBox "You selected First Class reservations"
End Sub
Private Sub BusinessClass()
    MsgBox "You selected Business Class reservations"
End Sub
Private Sub CoachClass()
    MsgBox "You selected Coach Class reservations"
End Sub
Private Sub Standby()
    MsgBox "You chose to fly standby"
End Sub
```

In a module I have the following:

```
Private ctlComboBoxHandler As New ComboBoxHandler
Sub AddComboBox()

    Set HostApp = Application

    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars("Test CommandBar").Delete

    Dim newBar As Office.CommandBar
    Set newBar = HostApp.CommandBars.Add(Name:="Test CommandBar", Temporary:=True)
    Dim newCombo As Office.CommandBarComboBox
    Set newCombo = newBar.Controls.Add(msoControlComboBox)
    With newCombo
        .AddItem "First Class", 1
        .AddItem "Business Class", 2
        .AddItem "Coach Class", 3
        .AddItem "Standby", 4
        .DropDownLines = 5
        .DropDownWidth = 75
        .ListHeaderCount = 0
    End With
    ctlComboBoxHandler.SyncBox newCombo
    newBar.Visible = True


End Sub


Sub test()

    Dim newBar As Office.CommandBar
    Set newBar = Application.CommandBars("Test CommandBar")
    Dim cmbox As Office.CommandBarComboBox
    Set cmbox = newBar.Controls(1)
    cmbox.Text = "Business Class"   ''<< I was hoping this would fire an event, but it does not! Same is true if I
End Sub
```

First I run AddComboBox and the events work fine if I manually change the ComboBox.
Then I run test() and the value displayed inside the ComboBox changes, but the event does not fire.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcombobox.text#example. This call is just giving the default item, but will not fire anything.

Comment: Looks like it is only a user change. You could (if you want) call the change-event, but you have to make ComboBoxEvent_Change public and add ctlComboBoxHandler.ComboBoxEvent_Change Application.CommandBars("Test CommandBar").Controls(1) to your Test Sub

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. The problem I have is that there is a large amount of code, some of which I don’t control/own, that has the ability to change the ComboBox. I assumed I could write some code that would detect the code I don’t own changing the ComboBox. There must be a way to do this, ideally from C#. I really want to avoid hooking into Window Messages. I assume this is behaviour is by design, but hoping there is a sensible/easy solution.